# Multi graphs in subplots for several dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, plot, iteration

I have several dataframes that are in one Folder, so an iterative for loop for importing and reading each dataset from the folder is writen, however to plot each dataset using subplots in order to plot them in 2 rows, 3 columns subplot. What is the best way to make that happen?
Is it a good idea to create a list and save the reading of the dataframe in it then iterate over this list to plot the elements using subbplot? Or is there any better idea?

````
```
`\<DataFrameList.append(dataFrame)
i=0
for i \<= len(DataFrameList)
DataFrameList\[i\]
figure, axis = plt.subplots(2, 3)

#
axis[0, 0, 0].plot(columnNameOfX, columnNameOfY, marker='o')
axis[0, 0, 0].set_title("Table Name"+tableName)

#
axis[0, 1, 0].plot(columnNameOfX, columnNameOfY, marker='+')
axis[0, 1, 0].set_title("Table Name"+tableName)

#
axis[1, 0, 0].plot(columnNameOfX, columnNameOfY, marker='-')
axis[1, 0, 0].set_title("Table Name"+tableName)

#
axis[1, 1, 0].plot(columnNameOfX, columnNameOfY, marker='.')
axis[1, 1, 0].set_title("Table Name"+tableName)

#
axis[1, 1, 1].plot(columnNameOfX, columnNameOfY, marker='.')
axis[1, 1, 1].set_title("Table Name"+tableName)

#
axis[0, 0, 1].plot(columnNameOfX, columnNameOfY, marker='.')
axis[0, 0, 1].set_title("Table Name"+tableName)

# Combine all the operations and display
plt.show()>`
```
````